# Align table vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a table. The table needs to be centered horizontally, and to vertically maintain the same margin from the top.

When I use the following CSS, it would center the table horizontally, but ignore the `top:50px`.
Then I used `position:absolute;` on CSS, then it would read `left:50px;` but would not center horizontally.

How can I achieve this? I am trying to stay away from `DIV`, but if it is the only way, I will use it.

```
<body>
    <table border="1" id="mainTable">
      <tr>
        <td width="150px" height="100">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="700px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="150px">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="800">   </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="100">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>

#mainTable{
    width:1000px;
    top:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding....so the table is positioning vertically the way you want but not centering horizontally, correct?

Comment: The final result I need is page center horizontally, and 50px from top of the page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you just add **`text-align:center`** in **`td`** tag,

```
#mainTable tr td{
    text-align:center;
}
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9kY92/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Just solved. I used position:relative; instead of position:absolute; And it worked.

Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #mainTable tr td{vertical-align:middle;}
```